# Interaction Tme

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-application, microinteractions, tab-bar

I am creating a mobile app for a Shopping mall. I have animated the tab bar icons that change from line-art style to filled icon when selected. A standard UX law states that the interaction should be max 400ms. Is it right to increase the animation time to 1sec or 1.5sec.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the [Doherty Threshold](https://lawsofux.com/doherty-threshold). The "rule" about <400ms that came from the Doherty & Thadani research paper was around productivity. So if your app is very task-based and about facilitating user productivity as much as possible, then good to stick to <400ms. But if your app is more exploratory and content-based, probably fine to increase animation time if you feel you have a reason for it.